# RMySQL dbWriteTable only import the first line?

Tags: mysql, rmysql

I have a 80 * 5 data.frame df using

```
dbWriteTable(mydb, name = "fooDB", df, field.types = dbtypes, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

to import to MySQL database. However, it only imports the first row of df.

Does anyone have similar problem? Or anyone has some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem and just share with all you guys.

The former table defined in MySQL server has a primary key of type int() but the column of data.frame in R is beyond 4 bytes.

Just change the type of primary key to bigint() which is 8 bytes format.