# R and DBI dbWriteTable connection to MySQL/MariaDB only imports first row

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb, dbi

I'm using an AWS mariaDB to store some data. My idea was to do the full management with the DBI package. However, I have found that DBI only imports the first row of the data when I try to write a table in the db. I have to use `DBI::dbCreateTable` and `dbx::dbxInsert`. I can't figure out why `DBI` is not importing the full data frame.

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401837/rmysql-dbwritetable-only-import-the-first-line) but the conclusion is not quite clear. This is the code/output:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "my_odbc", timeout = 10)

 ## Example 1 - doesn't work
 DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "test1", mtcars)
 DBI::dbReadTable(con, "test1")
  row_names mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4


 # Example 2 - doesn't work
 DBI::dbCreateTable(con, "test2", mtcars)
 DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "test2", mtcars)
[1] 1
 DBI::dbReadTable(con, "test2")
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4

 # Example 3 - does work.
 DBI::dbCreateTable(con, "test3", mtcars)
 dbx::dbxInsert(con, "test3", mtcars)
 DBI::dbReadTable(con, "test3")
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and if you aren't careful with how you define and use your primary keys you get this issue. The first row is allowed as its the first with that primary key and then the rows after are blocked and hence dont get inserted.